# How to fix "Self Hosting Font" not loading

Tags: css

Setting up a website, but the custom font isn't loading.

The font (logo) shows up on different desktop browsers, but it never shows on mobile browsers. I'm at my wits' end. Here's two different versions of what I've tried in the CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Haettenschweiler';
  src: url('hs-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('hs-regular?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('hs-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('hs-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('hs-regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('hs-regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

AND

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Haettenschweiler';
  src: url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/hs-regular-webfont.svg#geomanistregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Again, the desktop sites load as requested. But not the mobile ones.

Comment: Try referring to the font files from the root path (e.g. "/fonts/hs-regular.eot", or however the pathing should work)

Comment: maybe try putting the more standard font file tops on top (like woff and ttf) and put the less used ones like eot as fallback on the bottom

Comment: When you say it's loading on the desktop but not on mobile, I suspect it might be because of the aggressive caching on mobile browsers. Are you sure you cleared the mobile browser's cache when testing? What happens if you use an emulated mobile browser in devtools?

Comment: I've tried adjusting the root path, and listed woff and ttf first to no success.

I cleared the cache on Chrome (iPhone) and tried reloading. Nada. The emulated browser in devtools shows it as "working".